# How to test Picasa content provider in Android

Tags: android, picasa

I am trying to reproduce some exceptions my android application is getting during my activity's Image Chooser intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), INTENT_REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

Does anyone know how I can reproduce the steps that return a picasa content provider uri like this:
content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5893756913818770722

Comment: plz refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14092776/1944666

Comment: I did see that, however I want to do my own testing, so I'm trying to reproduce it.