# Getting Image path from URI not working for Picasa folder

Tags: android

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA));
```

> Unlike other folders like Camera, Screenshots, Foursquare etc.., The
>   Pictures from Picasa folder have less no.of columns, of which `_data` is not
>   there

*and Hence I get the Exception:*

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column'_data' does not exist**

There is a column named `picasa_id` and a Constant in android:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.PICASA_ID
```

Will that help in getting the correct image path?

Also if I had to download the image from the folder and save in my-app-images folder and then get the actual path. **How will I even know that the image URI is from Picasa?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an image from Gallery on from the Picasa//Google + synced folders doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764392/getting-an-image-from-gallery-on-from-the-picasa-google-synced-folders-doesn)