# PathURI from the camera library crashes

Tags: android

I am selecting a picture from the android device library as follows

```
public static void showFileChooser(Activity activity) {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
}
```

and trying to get `realPathFromURI` as follows, but idx always returns -1. I wonder what I am missing.

[image]

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Update 1:**

[image]

**Update 2:**
I even tried the following, path returns null

[image]

Comment: have you added read write permission in manifeast.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did. please see my updated question,I have added manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546101/get-real-path-for-uri-android

Comment: please check my update-2, which your mark duplication, still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you selecting picture from any synced device folder like google drive?

Comment: yes, I select google drive and also download folder.

Comment: @casillas :- Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are selecting image from devices synced folder then it must be the problem with image URI, Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11764392/1384010) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30453641/1384010).

Hope this will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

use media projection

```
 public static String getPath(Uri uri, Activity mActivity) {        
            try {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = mActivity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();           
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            } 
        }
```

Just use getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) to get an InputStream from a URI. in case of drive path

if input stream contains null you need to integrate drive api

Comment: please see the update in my question after I have applied your solution, still getting the error.